# Mac Pro (4,1; early 2009) won't shutdown

Tags: macos, mac-pro, shutdown

This issue is with a Mac Pro (4,1; early 2009) running OS X 10.9.4 Mavericks.

I have a strange problem, when I try to shutdown my Mac Pro. I get the grey screen with the activity indicator, but it does not shutdown, the indicator keeps spinning and spinning.

I figured out how to run the Mac in verbose mode in order to locate the problem. So I think this is the relevant part from `Console.app`:

```
02.09.14 21:01:34,654 com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[320]: (com.apple.PackageKit.InstallStatus) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
02.09.14 21:01:34,700 WindowServer[160]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 52227
02.09.14 21:01:34,703 WindowServer[160]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 52227
02.09.14 21:01:34,703 WindowServer[160]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 52227
02.09.14 21:01:34,704 WindowServer[160]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 52227
02.09.14 21:01:34,704 WindowServer[160]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 52227
02.09.14 21:01:34,733 LaCie Network Assistant[472]: windowWillClose
02.09.14 21:01:34,734 LaCie Network Assistant[472]: windowWillClose
02.09.14 21:01:34,733 com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[320]: (com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarn[478]) Exited: Killed: 9
02.09.14 21:01:34,734 LaCie Network Assistant[472]: windowWillClose
02.09.14 21:01:34,735 LaCie Network Assistant[472]: windowWillClose
02.09.14 21:01:34,735 LaCie Network Assistant[472]: windowWillClose
02.09.14 21:01:34,735 LaCie Network Assistant[472]: windowWillClose
02.09.14 21:01:34,738 com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[320]: (com.intego.commonservices.integomenu[433]) Exited: Killed: 9
02.09.14 21:01:34,739 com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.ShareKitHelper[407]) Exited: Killed: 9
02.09.14 21:01:34,742 NotificationCenter[402]: Connection interrupted.
02.09.14 21:01:34,745 UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: [UserAgentDied:142] User Agent @port=35335 Died
02.09.14 21:01:34,746 com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[320]: (com.apple.iTunesHelper.108800[442]) Exited with code: 1
02.09.14 21:01:34,748 com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[320]: ([0x0-0x3a03a].com.apple.AppleSpell[613]) Exited: Killed: 9
02.09.14 21:01:34,749 com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[320]: (com.apple.ImageCaptureExtension2.26432[569]) Exited: Killed: 9
02.09.14 21:01:34,756 com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[320]: (com.apple.UserEventAgent-Aqua[354]) Exited: Killed: 9
02.09.14 21:01:34,855 com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[320]: (com.apple.gamed[454]) Exited: Killed: 9
02.09.14 21:01:34,856 com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[320]: (2BUA8C4S2C.com.agilebits.onepassword-osx-helper[410]) Exited: Killed: 9
02.09.14 21:01:40,873 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
02.09.14 21:01:40,873 com.apple.kextd[12]: Rescanning kernel extensions.
02.09.14 21:01:40,873 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
02.09.14 21:01:41,263 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
02.09.14 21:01:41,263 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
02.09.14 21:01:41,303 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
02.09.14 21:01:41,305 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
02.09.14 21:01:42,000 kernel[0]: Resetting IOCatalogue.
02.09.14 21:01:42,111 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
02.09.14 21:01:42,113 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
02.09.14 21:01:42,195 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
02.09.14 21:01:42,195 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
02.09.14 21:01:42,202 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
02.09.14 21:01:42,205 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
02.09.14 21:01:44,767 loginwindow[89]: ERROR | -[ApplicationManager quitPrivateProcesses] | Private process did not quit
02.09.14 21:01:44,823 sessionlogoutd[714]: sessionlogoutd Launched
02.09.14 21:01:44,835 sessionlogoutd[714]: DEAD_PROCESS: 89 console
02.09.14 21:01:44,840 loginwindow[89]: ERROR | -[Application hardKill:] | Application hardKill returned -600
02.09.14 21:01:44,901 airportd[111]: _doAutoJoin: Already associated to “FlooNetwork2”. Bailing on auto-join.
02.09.14 21:01:45,763 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
02.09.14 21:01:45,767 com.apple.kextd[12]: Rescanning kernel extensions.
02.09.14 21:01:45,767 shutdown[716]: halt by _spotlight: 
02.09.14 21:01:45,000 kernel[0]: Kext loading now disabled.
02.09.14 21:01:45,000 kernel[0]: Kext unloading now disabled.
02.09.14 21:01:45,000 kernel[0]: Kext autounloading now disabled.
02.09.14 21:01:45,000 kernel[0]: Kernel requests now disabled.
02.09.14 21:01:45,767 shutdown[716]: SHUTDOWN_TIME: 1409684505 767090
02.09.14 21:01:45,793 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
02.09.14 21:01:45,797 virusbarrierb[267]: Unloading real-time scanner...
```

Comment: So you have lost your admin privileges?  do a hard shut down (hold power button till it shuts down), then start again to see if the problem has fixed it self. Also kill the LaCie Network Assistant.

Comment: Hi Buscar. I created a second user without admin privileges, which is my "personal/everyday/normal" user. A hard shutdown does not fix the problem. I always have to do a hard shutdown, because this problem happens every time I want to shutdown my Mac. I don't know If this is important but my user folder is on a second hard drive and my system and user hard drive are both encrypted with FileVault.

Comment: Does the shut down problem also happen when using the admin account?

Comment: Yes. The problem also happen when using the admin account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Log I see two events preventing the shut down.

```
02.09.14 21:01:44,767 loginwindow[89]: ERROR | -[ApplicationManager quitPrivateProcesses] | Private process did not quit

02.09.14 21:01:44,840 loginwindow[89]: ERROR | -[Application hardKill:] | Application hardKill returned -600
```

Indicating you have a application that refuses to quit. I assume it is the LaCie Network Assistant.

Also, in one case the Spotlight was holding the shutdown, that can be easily solved by disabling spotlight for your second drive to test.

For the

```
02.09.14 21:01:40,873 com.apple.kextd[12]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
```

The solution for this is to run following in Terminal:

```
sudo chown root:admin /
```

Comment: First I tried the easiest thing. Quit the Lacie network assistant. Though still no shutdown. I will try to shutdown other menu bar apps step by step and report...

Comment: It seems that one of the menu bar applications caused the shutdown problem. I haven't figured out which one, but surprisingly it wasn't the LaCie Network Asssistant and neither the Intego Menu Item. I will report which software caused the shutdown problem as soon as I figured this out.

Comment: You suggested also to run `sudo chown root:admin`in Terminal. What does this command exactly do? Thanks so far for your help.

Comment: It will get rid off the  "Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root" errors.

Comment: Yeah I think otherwise you wouldn't suggest it. But I meant something like "`chown` changes the permission of files". But on which file/folder does this command apply? The root of the system? Does this apply on all subfolders? I am just really cautious with terminal commands. Especially when they start with sudo.

Comment: It is used to fix the User directory ownership. But you are right with the "sudo", since I can not guarantee you the outcome or if you make a typo, better let it go or read this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/chown.8.html

Comment: Using the `Disk Utitlity` wouldn't have the same effect?

Comment: nope, disk utility only fixes the disk level, not the user/root permissions.

Comment: you are welcome, just come back with more problems to solve :)

Comment: I will. Promised :)